# Ignore password field if empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have a "profile edit" section on a website I am creating which allows users to update their e-mail address and password. They work great, but at the moment, they are forced to change their password.

Can I set it so no field is required, but info will update based on whether or not there's input?

At the moment, I'm getting this if I don't enter a password:

The parameter 'newPassword' must not be empty.

Thanks

```
using System;
using nForum.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace nForum.usercontrols.nForum.membership
{
    public partial class ForumMemberProfileEdit : BaseForumUsercontrol
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadProfile();
            }
        }

        private void LoadProfile()
        {
            if (CurrentMember == null | IsBanned)
            {
                membereditprofile.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //We have a Member logged in fill the data
                tbEmail.Text = CurrentMember.MemberEmail;
            }
        }

        protected void BtnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
            var cMem = Member.GetCurrentMember();
            cMem.Email = tbEmail.Text;

            MembershipUser u;
            u = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
            u.ChangePassword(u.ResetPassword(), tbNewPassword.Text);

            //Save member
            cMem.Save();

            //Generate member Xml Cache
            cMem.XmlGenerate(new System.Xml.XmlDocument());

            // Show message
            Response.Redirect(string.Concat(CurrentPageAbsoluteUrl, "?m=", library.GetDictionaryItem("ProfileUpdated")));
        }
    }
}
```

And the ASP

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ForumMemberProfileEdit.ascx.cs" Inherits="nForum.usercontrols.nForum.membership.ForumMemberProfileEdit" %>

<div id="membereditprofile" class="membereditprofile" runat="server">

            <dl class="form">

                <!-- E-mail field -->
                <dt><label for="<%= tbEmail.ClientID %>">Email</label></dt>
                <dd><asp:TextBox ToolTip="Enter email address" CssClass="required email" ID="tbEmail" runat="server" /></dd>

                <!-- New Password field -->
                <dt><label for="<%= tbNewPassword.ClientID %>">New Password</label></dt>
                <dd><asp:TextBox ToolTip="Enter your new password" CssClass="pass1" onkeyup="checkPass()" TextMode="password" ID="tbNewPassword" runat="server" /></dd>

                <!-- Confirm New Password field -->
                <dt><label for="<%= tbConfirmPassword.ClientID %>">Confirm Password</label></dt>
                <dd><asp:TextBox ToolTip="Confirm your new password" CssClass="pass2" onkeyup="checkPass()" TextMode="password" ID="tbConfirmPassword" runat="server" /></dd>

                <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
                <asp:Label id="Msg" ForeColor="maroon" runat="server" />

                <!-- Compare Passwords -->
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbNewPassword" ControlToCompare="tbConfirmPassword" CssClass="hideError" ErrorMessage="Password does not match!" ></asp:CompareValidator>
                <!-- Compare Passwords -->
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbConfirmPassword" ControlToCompare="tbNewPassword" CssClass="hideError" ErrorMessage="Password does not match!" ></asp:CompareValidator>

                <dt> </dt>
                <dd><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update Profile" onclick="BtnSubmitClick" CssClass="btnSubmit" /></dd>

            </dl>

</div>
```

Comment: Post your aspx markup that you have for this page.

Comment: Where are you getting "The parameter 'newPassword' must not be empty."? I can't see it anywhere obvious so I'm wondering if it is in the change password method in which case the obvious solution is don't call that method if the password is empty. ;-) Stack traces of error messages are very useful if available.

Comment: "tbNewPassword.Text" - Which is my password field would essentially be the "newPassword" string. When there's no input it's chucking out that error. So just add a condition to "ChangePassword"?

Comment: if it is `u.ChangePassword` that is giving you the error then yes, jsut do a `String.IsNullOrEmpty` check and if it is then don't call teh changepassword method. Also you should hopefully have a stack trace or better error messages that give line numbers in files that you can use to confirm exactly which line that you have given us has the error on. I am having to make educated guesses abotu where it is which is why I am not happy putting in a definitive answer at this stage.